# Fix a function returning duplicates over time?

Tags: python, random

I have a function here that returns a 4 digit string. The problem is that when I run the function like 500 times or more, it starts to return duplicates. How to avoid that?

My Function:

```
import random
def CreatePass():
    Num = str(random.randint(1000, 9999)
    return Num
```

Comment: Random functions usually don't have the constraint of not returning duplicates. They only have to be random. You have to implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: oh i see, but why so many dislikes for this post? DONT PEOPLE KNOW THAT THERE ARE YOUNG PROGRAMMERS ON THIS WEBSITE TOO?

Comment: @KingMak Just because you're young, you're not exempt from logic.

Comment: What a shocker, the chance of a collision when choosing an element out of 8999 elements 500 times is 5.6%. Combining the limitations of pseudorandom choice, I wonder why you have that happen!

Comment: Sometimes people like to pile on... your question is no worse than a lot of questions that are not downvoted.

Comment: To be fair. The OP is asking how to avoid duplicates - they're not expressing surprise that it does so. Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: @alexis Arguable. The title is vague, it lacks enough descriptive tags, there's a syntax error in the code, and OP has a Naruto avatar to boot.

Comment: I see 5 dislikes and 3 answers, with 1 constructive comment, if you have to down vote, then explain why and offer a better solution.

Comment: Haha, ok the avatar is a smack magnet, I admit it. But @King is absolutely right: All these downvotes and nobady had (yet) bothered to say why.

Comment: @alexis Tooltip of the downvote button: "This question does **not show any research effort**; it is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)" (emphasis mine)

Comment: I thought this site was about code RATHER THEN AVATARS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Martijn's solution is enough since you only need to store and shuffle 9000 numbers. If you want numbers from a bigger range and you know (approximately) how many numbers you'll need, there's a better way: The function [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) will give you numbers in the desired range `without` repetition. For example, to get 500 distinct six-digit numbers you'd use:

```
selected = random.sample(xrange(100000, 1000000), 500)
```

Comment: Nice, this answer was more understandable for my young mind and easier ti implement too.

Comment: so this means that random.sample does not return duplicates at all? could you explain a little bit more

Comment: Yes, it does. Look at the documentation for it (linked). Also look up `xrange` while you're at it.

Comment: Hmm, ambiguous answer: Yes it does mean that `random.sample` does not return duplicates. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 11):

Generate a list, shuffle that and pop from it each time the function is called:

```
import random

def CreatePass(_numbers=[]):
    if not _numbers:
        _numbers[:] = range(1000, 10000)
        random.shuffle(_numbers)              
    return str(_numbers.pop())
```

Note that this re-generates the `_numbers` list once you've run out, but then you've used up all 8999 possible numbers and would have to accept repetitions anyway.

Comment: Use a [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead of list for faster pop operations.

Answer (score 2):

Could just roll your own, and hope not to exhaust it:

```
from random import shuffle
def myrandom(start, end):
    possible = range(start, end)
    shuffle(possible)
    for i in possible:
        yield str(i)

randoms = myrand(1000, 9999)
print next(randoms)
print next(randoms)
# etc...
```

You'll get a `StopIteration` when it's exhausted though...

Answer (score 0):

A random sequence without duplicates isn't random.

You can reduce the likelihood of duplicates by increasing the range of possible values.

Alternatively, you can record previous return values, and choose a new value if it has been previously returned.

Finally, you could generate the whole sequence, then shuffle it.

Of course, you then need to figure out what to do once you have exhausted the possible return values, as well as the whether the behaviour once there are only a small number of possible return values is actually desirable.

Also, you should comply with standard Python coding standards.